# Why can't I call java-apns getInactiveDevices() method in ColdFusion 8?

Tags: java, coldfusion, apple-push-notifications, coldfusion-8, javapns

I'm building an application to send push notifications to Apple devices from ColdFusion 8 using notnoop's java-apns library, and when calling a method in the library, I'm receiving "method not found" exception, even though the method is [clearly defined in the library](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/master/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsService.java) (line 161). I am able to send push notifications successfully, just this one method is not working. What is possibly wrong here???

Code:

```
<cfscript>
    LOCAL.APNSService =
        CreateObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.APNS").newService()
            .withCert(
                "MyCert.p12",
                "MyPassword"
                )
            .withProductionDestination()
            .build();

    LOCAL.APNSService.start();
    LOCAL.InactiveDevices = LOCAL.APNSService.getInactiveDevices();

    LOCAL.payload =
        CreateObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.APNS").newPayload()
            .badge(1)
            .alertBody("Hello, world.")
            .sound("PushNotification.caf")
            .build();

    LOCAL.APNSNotification =
        CreateObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.SimpleApnsNotification")
            .init(
                JavaCast("string", LOCAL.MyDeviceToken),
                JavaCast("string", LOCAL.payload)
                );
    LOCAL.APNSService.push(LOCAL.APNSNotification);

    LOCAL.APNSService.stop();
</cfscript>
```

Exception:

```
The getInactiveDevices method was not found.
```

Stack Trace:

```
coldfusion.runtime.java.MethodSelectionException: The getInactiveDevices method was not found.
at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.findMethodUsingCFMLRules(ObjectHandler.java:322)
at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:527)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2300)
```

Comment: Shot in the dark.. I remember reading something about a conflict in certain versions of CF, due to the usage of [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) . Check the CF `\lib` directory. Does it include a version of the slf4j jar? If yes, that could be the problem. Use a zip tool to open the apns jar and remove the entire `org.slf4j.*` package. Then restart CF.

Comment: @Leigh I checked the CF_ROOT\lib directory, and there is no slf4j.jar, nor is there one in the JRE libe directory.

Comment: Hm.. it may have been a CF9+ issue. It was a long shot anyway. Unfortunately I do not have access to CF8 right now. For grins, try creating an instance of one of the classes just be certain ie `createObject("java", "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory")`. If it throws a class not found error, then you are right.

Comment: `<cfset LOCAL.Object = createObject("java", "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory") />` does not throw an error.

Comment: Ugh.. silly me. That is not a good test. It would work anyway since you already have the agns jar with dependencies (includes slf4j) in your class path. I assume you dumped the actual object ie `LOCAL.APNSService` and verified the method is there? Is there anything else listed in the stack trace OR CF error logs? Sometimes the cause is further down in the chained message.

Comment: @Leigh I can find nothing else about the error. That's why I turned here. Very frustrating.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, I did not have a CF8 install handy or I would have just run the code to try and reproduce it. Anyway, glad you found a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benn Linger created this workaround: http://www.bennlinger.com/uploads/get_inactive_devices.txt